# When focusing on element, the outline blinks in different colours. How to make it work normally?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, bootstrap-4, sass

I'm getting a strange behaviour with `:focus-visible` in Chrome, Edge and Canary. I want the anchors on a navbar to display a purple outline when focused with the keyboard. Their class include `outline: $the-purple-color auto 1px !important`.

However, when I focus those elements, for a very brief moment, I get a black outline, and then immediately switches to the correct color. That black color seems to come from a "user agent stylesheet" with the pseudoclass `:focus-visible { outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 1px; }`, where `-webkit-focus-ring-color` seems to be black. I believe this is the source of the black outline because, if I turn off my custom class, it'll default to the "user agent stylesheet" one.

I haven't found that phenomenon on the Internet. How can I keep my outline in one solid colour without blinking to the default one?

EDIT: Here's the code:

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-12">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a>Home</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

```scss
header {
  &.main-header {
    .navbar {
      li {
        a {
          &:focus-visible {
            // $menu-hover-color: #bf00ff
            outline: $menu-hover-color auto 1px !important;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: A list of things I've already tried:

- Changed the variable for the hex colour.
- Changed the variable for another colour.
- Normalized the outline of `*:focus-visible` to `0`.
- Normalized the outline of `*:focus-visible` to another colour. I still get the black blink.
- Gave the wrapping `li` an `outline-colour` other than purple and black to see if the black blink was picked up by this element.

Comment: can you atach your code?

Comment: I edited my post to add the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that another class was adding a `transition: ... all` that had unintended consequences.